# How to Handle two await function?

Tags: node.js

I run this type of code

```
var facebook_data = async function(system_data,business_data,cb){
    try{
        var formData = {
            grant_type: "fb_exchange_token",
            client_id: system_data.fb_facebook_api_key,
            client_secret: system_data.fb_facebook_api_secret,
            fb_exchange_token: business_data.fb_accessToken
        };
        var url = "/oauth/access_token";
        var access_token_data = await fbAPIGet(url,formData);
        console.log(access_token_data);
        // business_access_token_log.info(access_token_data)
        // cb();
        if(access_token_data) {
            await createAccessTokenLogs(system_data,business_data);
            await updateAccessToken(system_data,business_data,access_token_data);
            cb();
        } else {
            business_access_token_log.info("No Data Found From Facebook");
        }
    }catch(err){
        business_access_token_log.info("Error in Get Facebook From Data");
        business_access_token_log.info(err);
        cb();
    }
};
```

but when i run this code only first await(await createAccessTokenLogs(system_data,business_data)) be executed not other one so please suggest me best code to run both ;

Comment: Sounds like the `createAccessTokenLogs` never resolves (or rejects), if the next `await updateAccessToken` line doesn't run? (you'll need to debug your `createAccessTokenLogs`)

Comment: Quick note... Why are you using callbacks in combination with async/await?

Comment: can you console anything in both `createAccessTokenLogs` and `updateAccessToken` and check when are they executing